# CORS API call issue in IONIC after adding WKWebView

Tags: ios, xml, cordova, ionic3, wkwebview

I have added WKWebView in my application and as suggested by document for CORS API call now I need to call it through HTTP call.
I have added necessary headers as well. But I am getting 200 ok and XML data in error block. My code is below:

```
    let headers = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Accept , Origin, X-Requested-With',
     'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'X-Custom-header',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET , POST , OPTIONS'
  };

    this.httpIonic.get('http://www.myserver.com/blog/feed/', {}, headers)
      .then(data => {

        console.log("--------------------------res:::::");
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data.data); // data received by server
        console.log(data.headers);
        console.log("--------------------------res:::::");

      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + JSON.stringify(error));

        // console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + error);
        // console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + error.status);
        // console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + error.error); // error message as string
        console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + JSON.stringify(error.headers));
        // console.log("--------------------------error:::::" + error);

      });
```

Issue is when I run application in iOS simulator I got error response and also getting xml value which ideally I should get in response but if I print error.error its showing that xml.

Comment: you havent set cors at all.. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` these headers should be sent by server side not your app... Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @SurajRao I have checked many solutions like : https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/ . People suggests that if while requesting I add this headers this should solve my issue.

Comment: you should set them in _server side_..

Answer (score -1):

First of all you haven't implemented CORS headers in your API/web services files, what you have done is that you have written those headers in your js file but that is wrong. 
Your CORS headers are right but file is wrong.

Also,

You can use ionic native http plugin to resolve cors issue.

I have used this in our projects successfully to resolve cors issue.

As per ionic official documentation:

> "If it is not an possibility to implement or configure CORS in the
>   server, there is a native plugin that can “proxy” the HTTP requests
>   using native code, so CORS can be completely bypassed"

Here is the link of this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Comment: That plugin is suggested by ionic itself so if someone is using ionic wkwebview plugin then they must install this native http plugin as well , there is no other code required , just need to install that plugin